# CSS: Position breaks after a hidden html tag shows

Tags: css, html

First Image: [image]

Second Image: [image]

Problem: why in the second image there is a space between the yellow and green after a hidden html tag shows please help? how should i fix this? Thank you so much.

Here's my code in html

```
<div id="login">
    <?php
    session_start();
    $errmsg = array();
    if(isset($_SESSION['errmsg'])&&is_array($_SESSION['errmsg'])&&count($_SESSION['errmsg'])>0){
        foreach($_SESSION['errmsg'] as $msg){
            echo '<p id="error"><img src="img/error.png" alt="Login error!">'.$msg.'</p>';
        }
        unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
            <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" required>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>
    <?php
    include 'functions/functions.php';
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $result=AuthenticateUser($_POST['email'],$_POST['pass']);
        if($result){

        }
        else
            $errmsg[]='Login error:please check your e-mail & password';
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
            session_write_close();
            header('location:index.php');
            exit();
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Here's my code for css

```
label, input#pass, input#register{
    display:block;
}
p#error {
    color:#FF0000;
}
div#nav{
    background-image:url('../img/nav.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div#nav, a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
div#login, div#register {
    background-image:url('../img/form.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: You had best check this out in Firebug. Simply point at the element and see why there is a space. Probably some CSS setting of the error message.

Comment: <p> will have a margin top on it. add some CSS like : `p {margin:0;padding:0;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the default styles for `<p>`. Try changing `<p id="error">` to `<div id="error">` and see if that fixes it. You could also try adding `margin-top:0px;` to the style rule for `p#error`.

If either of those solutions fix it, then problem was because of the default top-margin value for the `<p>` tag. The margin pushed down the start of the `<div id="login">` and caused the gap.

Comment: It is indeed the (default) margin of the `<p>`. I always solve this problem by setting a `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` of `1px` to the containing element (in this case `div#login`) to prevent the margin from collapsing.

Comment: Yes sir it works! thanks, i just add margin:0,padding:0 to my p :)